# How to extract the word after "?"

Tags: python

> /test/?testOne

I want to extract the word after "?" and store in a var.

```
var = testOne
```

Comment: Is this a url that you are trying to get the query parameters?

Comment: Where are the "..." for your string you put in var?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split on '?' and get the last part :

```
S = '/test/?testOne'
var = S.split('?')[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`var = "/test/?testOne".split("?")[1]`

This splits your string by the question mark and selects the second half.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you only want last value after `?`, that's why I am using `-1` as index. This will return everything in string after last '?'.

```
s = "/test/?testOne"
var = s.split("?")[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going with `regex`. `(?<=\?)\w+` captures any word that is preceded by a `?`.

```
import re

txt = "\test\?testOne"
match = re.search("(?<=\?)\w+", text).group()

print(match)
```

Output:

```
testOne
```

Comment: I think regex is kind of overkill for this situation.

Comment: @JammyDodger you're probably right, I just really enjoy it.